# Wyeast 3724 hot fermentation

Tags: yeast

As I'm living in Singapore I'm trying out an experimental all extract recipe consisting of pilsner malt, crystal malt and amber malt together with Wyeast 3724. I've hopped it with Centennial and cascade and was considering dry hopping with Amarillo. (Yes, I am trying to brew an IPA with Saison)

Temperatures in Singapore are quite steady ranging from 28 degrees C in the night to 32 degrees C during the day in my house. This made me use the saison wyeast as it's recommended for hot fermentation.

I'm wondering now what the estimate is for it to fully ferment, considering the temperature here is in the ranges Dupont uses for fermenting. I've seen people say 4 weeks and some even said up to 6 months. Any recommendations for a target gravity?

Comment: And what's your original gravity? And mash temperatures? Also, be prepared to get something that's more saison than AIPA.

Comment: Does mashing still apply if you are doing pure extract?

Comment: Nope. Then it's about the extract making process... but that you cannot know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Saison is mostly about the yeast. So what you're brewing will taste strongly like one. No way you are getting AIPA that way. Still, you may get an interesting "bastard" brew and I would really like to try.

From what I've read, peoples' experiences are pretty consistent with [manufacturer's claims](https://www.wyeastlab.com/rw_yeaststrain_detail.cfm?ID=60). Fast fermentation to 1.035 S.G. Then it slows down, and it's either months, hot fermentation temperature (preferably over 30 degrees C), or second yeast strain. With your temperatures, it should be hot enough for this yeast to finish in weeks.